# Facebook Sharer can't get og:image although it exists in meta tags (worpress - woocomerce)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-sharer, yoast

For some reason Facebook sharer is not getting the og image specified in my meta tags.

I've tried scraping it again in Sharing debugger but still nothing...
Can anybody help?

For the first one it has cached something from a long time ago and for the second it can't even find the og:image

I use Yoast plugin for creating the meta tags

Comment: It appears to work fine, after a couple of re-scrapes …? First attempt showed me an error that the site was using an invalid SSL cert though (might have been a cached result), did you just recently change anything in that regard?

Comment: yup just fixed it with adding Facebook app id on yoast settings

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Had to add Facebook app id in the yoast configuration for Facebook. Hope that helps anyone else that comes across the same problem